# How should I handle exceptions in a PostgreSQL SQL script window?

Tags: postgresql

I have an SQL script that I am trying to execute in a PostgreSQL v10 SQL window using pgAdmin 4.  If it worked, the script would create three transactions.  However, the second transaction fails, and then I get an error saying "current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block".  I should probably be using an EXCEPTION statement, but I'm not sure how in an SQL window.  I can't use RAISE NOTICE in an SQL window, and I don't know how else to get PostgreSQL to tell me what the error is.

Here's a little example:

```
start transaction;
select * from xyz;
commit;

start transaction;
select 2 / 1;
commit;
```

Instead of getting an error message telling that table xyz does not exist, I get the transaction aborted error message.